# How to create bootstrap big content menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, megamenu

I am new to bootstrap and i want to create a mega-menu in which there should be categories containing other sub-categories with a lot of content like links/images.

I have simply no idea how i would do something like this based on the bootstrap nav documentation.

I have an example of such a site, check [here](http://theme.stepofweb.com/Smarty/v2.0.0/HTML_BS4/pack-megashop-home-1.html). See their navigation menu. What i want is a functionality similar to this menu.

Can anyone explain how i can achieve something like this? for example any method/concepts :)

A small demo / jsfiddle would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap then it can help you create responsive navs which are also collapsible on small screens but it doesn't have its own mega-menu. You can extend bootstrap nav into a mega-menu using Basic HTML, CSS or even jQuery if you know. You just need to place a lot of ul li (unordered lists) nestedly according to your needs and place hover rules over ul li.

In the end it becomes messy to here is a codepen link where you can visit and analyse the code.

https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/vZPgjz

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mega-dropdown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  background: #f0f0f0;
  background: url(https://pcbx.us/bfjb.jpg);
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #404041;
}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  width: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 285px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 283px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu>li>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu>li>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu>li ul>li>a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu>li ul>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu form {
  margin: 3px 20px;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MegaMenu</a>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">New in Stores</li>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                      <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                      <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                      <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.carousel -->
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                <form class="form" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                </form>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>
</div>

<h1 class="c-text"> Bootstrap Mega Menu </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for this good example. I have browsed the code and it can guide me on the right path. Very helpful :)